# Does $2^n-1=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} {n \choose i}$?

Tags: combinatorics

Does $2^n-1$ equal $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} {n \choose i}$?
I found this while trying to solve a problem. Is this true or not? I cannot find it on the internet.

Comment: Consider the binomial theorem.

$(x+y)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^{k} y^{n-k}$. Let $x = y = 1$. What happens? Also, what is $\binom{n}{0}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. By the binomial theorem, $$2^n - 1 = (1 + 1)^n - 1 = \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i} - \binom{n}{0} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \binom{n}{i}.$$

Comment: Ah... great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$
(1+1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

From a "probability" point of view
$$(p+q)^N=\sum_{n=0}^{N}{N \choose n}p^nq^{N-n}$$
if we take $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$ that will give
$$1=\sum_{n=0}^{N}{N \choose n}\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{1}{2^{N-n}}=\frac{1}{2^N}\sum_{n=0}^{N}{N \choose n}$$ and than $$2^N-1=\sum_{n=1}^{N}{N \choose n}$$
so yes, you are correct